# React Navigation: Send additional props in CustomDrawerContent

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In my React Native project, I'm using React Navigation (5) with a custom drawer. The Drawer Navigator looks like this with some screens in it.

```
<Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />} >
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

How can I pass some additional props to `CustomDrawerContent`? let's say I have some data like `user_type`. How can I send it along with props?

Answer (score 0):

let try this

```
const moreData = {}

<Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} moreData={moreData} />} >
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

then log your CustomDrawerContent props.

Comment: this does not work